# Having unweighted counts in the header of tbl_svysummary without stratifying the table

Tags: r, tidyverse, survey, gtsummary

I am wondering if there is a way to present unweighted counts in the header of a `tbl_svysummary` object without doing stratification using `by=`. I even tried `add_overall()` but it gives me the weighted count for the overall column while giving the unweighted counts for the stratified columns.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can use the modify_header() function. Check out the section under tbl_svysummary() for examples of unweighted Ns. https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify.html

Comment: It gives me `Error: Error processing `modify_*()` for column 'stat_0'.
`

Comment: What cute gives you the error?

Comment: `modify_header( list(
    stat_0  ~ "**Overall**, N = {n_unweighted} ({style_percent(p)}%)",
    stat_1 ~ "**Any**, N = {n_unweighted} ({style_percent(p)}%)",
    stat_2 ~ "**None**, N = {n_unweighted} ({style_percent(p,digits = 1)}%)"))`

Comment: I think the problem is coming from stat_0. This is the message I get Error: Error processing `modify_*()` for column 'stat_0'.

Comment: The quantity `n_unweighted` is not available for Overall columns (although, it is now available in the dev version of gtsummary). Update it to  `N_unweighted`